# How do I merge two queries using the Facebook SDK in C#?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, fql.multiquery

I am using Facebook C# SDK but there is not an overloaded method to pass in two queries as parameters. How can I merge two queries?

My Queries like this I have two Queries one is retrieving Name and second is retrieving Message so I want to show name and message to my application but the FQL deosn't support join and all so how I can do this eg.

```
var Query1 = fbApp.Query("SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())");

var newsFeed = fbApp.Query("SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0");
```

how I can get result name--> message.
Thanky you..!!

Comment: can you explain what do you want to do in details?

Comment: ya hi I have added my query just take look it should clear your question.

Comment: If you need named queries, check the solution out here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681786/fql-multiquery-query-syntax-when-passing-as-parameter][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681786/fql-multiquery-query-syntax-when-passing-as-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use multiquery in my application.  What you do is pass a string[] array into the .Query() command.

```
"SELECT uid, page_id, type  FROM page_admin WHERE uid = " + id
```

and

```
"SELECT uid, read_stream, status_update, photo_upload, publish_stream, offline_access FROM permissions WHERE uid IN (SELECT page_id FROM #query0)"
```

You don't get to name the queries, they come prenamed via the C# API.  Note it's #query0, #query1, etc...

When you get the data back, here's how I parsed it:

```
var pageAdmins = multiqueryResults[0].fql_result_set;
var permissions = multiqueryResults[1].fql_result_set;
```

Comment: That is fine but my Question is I have two Queries right and I want to show my result as name -> belongs to message so user can understand who has commente this message so the problem is user table has name and stream has a message how I can manage this.?

Comment: You will need to merge them programmatically with looping. Join actor_id on uid.